# Load an R matrix into H2O without csv

Tags: r, h2o

Is there a way to load a matrix into [`H2O`](http://0xdata.com/h2o/) from `R` without going over a file?

i.e. a direct alternative to

```
m = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol=2)
localH2O = h2o.init()
write.table(m, "m.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
h2o.importFile(localH2O, path="m.csv")
```

Comment: To my knowledge, no, you cannot. The package is built to handle things that would normally give base R trouble so I think the assumption is you will read things directly from your filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But of course....

To go from "h2o" to "R" the command is: "[as.data.frame.H2OParsedData](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/h2o/man/as.data.frame.html)"

From the example:

```
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init()
prosPath = system.file("extdata", "prostate.csv", package="h2o")
prostate.hex = h2o.importFile(localH2O, path = prosPath)
prostate.data.frame <- as.data.frame(prostate.hex)
summary(prostate.data.frame)
head(prostate.data.frame)
```

To go from "R" to "h2o" the command is: "[as.h2o](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/h2o/man/as.h2o.html)"

From the example, the code is:

```
data(iris)
summary(iris)
iris.r <- iris
iris.h2o <- as.h2o(localH2O, iris.r, key="iris.h2o")
class(iris.h2o)
```

so try this:

```
m = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol=2)
localH2O = h2o.init()
m2 <- as.h2o(client=localH2O, object=m)
class(m2)
```

Comment: That does seem to work, but is extremely slow when copying more than a toy example.

Comment: R is fundamentally slow.  Have you looked at loading compressed csv into h2o?

Comment: as.h2o still goes to file though, so this is not actually any faster than first writing to csv and then doing h2o.importFile - that's in fact exactly what as.h2o does...

Comment: The problem here definitely isn't R being slow, but just that passing data by going to file as h2o does is really slow... They should really fix this and provide an in-memory solution as the whole performance advantage of H2O is lost in this way...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the H2O functionality improved at the time of me reading this...

```
m2 <- as.h2o(x = m, destination_frame = "m2")
```

This will save R object m2 into H2O cluster